# "An arm bruises" vs "an arm is bruised"

Tags: verbs, verb-usage

Which is incorrect?

1. I have bruised my arm.
2. My arm has bruised.
3. My arm has been bruised.
4. My arm got bruised.

Answer (score 1):

#### All are correct,  but mean slightly different things.

As a native English speaker,  I would say that all of these sentences are correct, but they mean different things, so they might not be correct to use in certain situations,  depending on your intended meaning.

"I have bruised my arm" can mean either that you've bruised your arm at some point in the past, or that your arm is currently bruised as a result of your previous actions. Which meaning it would have would depend on context. It's also important to note that you're taking responsibility for the bruising of your arm, as opposed to the other statements in this list where you're attributing the bruising to the natural course of events, an outside force, or another person.

"My arm has bruised" is saying that your arm has developed a bruise, presumably due to a particular action. Its 5he sort of thing I could imagine someone saying after a sporting game when they're looking over themselves in the changing room.

"My arm has been bruised" You're saying that your arm has developed bruises at some point in the past. It's the sort of thing I could see a battered wife telling a police officer when describing how her husband has beaten her, for instance.

"My arm got bruised" Your arm has developed a bruise,  and its not your fault. Someone else did it, or it just naturally happened.

Also, to address the phrases in your title (which were different to the phrases in your actual question), "an arm bruises" is speaking about the bruisability of arms in general - you're saying that, in general,  arms can develop bruises, and doing so in a very posh register. Alternatively,  you're saying that out of a group of people, there is exactly one who is in the process of developing bruises on their arm. "An arm is bruised" on the other hand, is saying that out of a group of people, there is exactly one with a bruised arm.